# android IME does not go fullscrenn and extract ui on some platforms, is there any way to force this behavior?

Tags: android, android-layout

```
    <EditText
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/etUsername"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/username"
        android:background="@anim/custom_edit_text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
         />
```

this is my edit text and when I tap on it because of the keyboard the exittext can not be seen anymore, on my galaxy s3 the IME goes fullscreen, extracts UI and it's working perfectly, but on other platforms the keyboard appear over the edittext.

Comment: try to add this  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" properties to <activity tag in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: it's not working, but to make myself clear I want to go in fullscreen NOT to suppress this behavior.